# How to interpret t-test results?

Tags: python, interpretation

By using

```
stats.shapiro
stats.ttest_rel
```

I reached these results:

> ```
> (0.9338506460189819, 0.3452151119709015)
> (0.9339198470115662, 0.34597477316856384)
> Ttest_relResult(statistic=0.24688131296055482, pvalue=0.8088559103740811)
> ```

Can someone help me to interpret these results?

Comment: This seems like a better question for [stats.se]. Have you read the documentation on the functions? What _do_ you understand about your output, and what is your _specific_ question or questions about it?

Comment: Agreed that this isn't great for SF. A ttest_rel will test whether the means of two related samples are equal. P-values above alpha (usually 0.05) would suggest you cannot conclude there is a difference in the means. Below means you will conclude the means are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Shapiro-Wilk test is for normality.

Null Hypothesis in this case:  data was drawn from a normal distribution.

```
pvalue=0.8088
```

p-value>0.05 ==> fail to reject the Null Hypothesis.

You can say is that the data are not inconsistent with a Gaussian distribution

Comment: The test doesn't establish normal distribution as a fact . You have just failed to reject it as a hypothesis.

Comment: Yes that's why said more likely. But you are not completely agreeing. You can either reject or fail to reject. But there is nothing as accept word in hypothesis. Thanks for pointing this out I guess I have to reframe the sentence it might create confusion.

Comment: @Nick Cox: Can you provide some good resources to understand statistics in depth, since you have rich knowledge in stats. It will be very helpful to me :).

Comment: There are several threads here about good textbooks etc.

Comment: Failure to reject the null does not mean the data are more likely to come from a normal.  It means that we can not rule out the proposition that it came from a normal

Comment: @DemetriPananos: I updated the answer. Source: https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/statistics/stat_interpreting_results_normality.htm

Thanks for pointing out. If this is not okay can you tell what should be the correct statement. I just studied this topic few weeks back so I might be wrong at interpreting it.

Comment: @Pygirl I think your edit is fine.  Language in statistics is *always* a pain point.  We want to say something informative, but we don't want to oversell our conclusions.  It is a practice that takes time :)

Comment: @Pygirl can I say both variables violate the assumption if normality? Or the data doesn't seem to be normally distributed?